# Visually/graphically compare intervals on a number line

Tags: data-visualization, visualization

I created a simple visualization to compare two intervals, A and B, using a number line:
[image: Comparison of intervals A and B]

Is there a better way to visualize this comparison? I thought about putting A and B both on top of the number line:
[image: Comparison of intervals A and B on top of each other]

But now my concern is that it looks like B has a higher value along some hidden y-axis. Are there existing mechanisms to compare intervals? It seems like a common need.